# How to use log4go with configuration file?

Tags: go, logging

I have been trying to use log4go in golang. But I could not find a proper example where log4go configuration properties were used like rotation,maxSize etc to create a logger. Can somebody provide a example? I have referred to many sites.

Comment: I have been referring to https://godoc.org/github.com/alecthomas/log4go this site

Answer (score 0):

log4go is not well documented, I found some documentation in the [original repository](https://code.google.com/archive/p/log4go/wikis/LogWriters.wiki).
If you can, I'd use a different library like [logrus](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus), has a better documentation, examples and is actively developed.

Comment: Logrus does not support writing into two different logs file right? Even i was using Logrus, i moved to log4go because there was requirement to write logs in two different files

Comment: Did you take a look to [lfshook](https://github.com/rifflock/lfshook)? It should solve your problem

Comment: Ifshook writes to different files based on log levels. Am I correct? I need to log based on certain some decoding of bytes. Can i somehow specify that instead of log levels?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use the logConfig xml, for example:

```
<code>
    <logging>
    <filter enabled="true">
      <tag>stdout</tag>
      <type>console</type>
      <!-- level is (:?FINEST|FINE|DEBUG|TRACE|INFO|WARNING|ERROR) -->
      <level>INFO</level>
      </filter>
      <filter enabled="true">
            <tag>file</tag>
            <type>file</type>
            <level>INFO</level>
            <property name="filename"><log file Path></property>

            <!--
              %T - Time (15:04:05 MST)
              %t - Time (15:04)
              %D - Date (2006/01/02)
              %d - Date (01/02/06)
              %L - Level (FNST, FINE, DEBG, TRAC, WARN, EROR, CRIT)
              %S - Source
              %M - Message
              It ignores unknown format strings (and removes them)
              Recommended: "[%D %T] [%L] (%S) %M"
            -->
            <property name="format">[%D %T] [%L] (%S) %M</property>
            <property name="rotate">true</property> <!-- true enables log rotation, otherwise append -->
            <property name="maxsize">10M</property> <!-- \d+[KMG]? Suffixes are in terms of 2**10 -->
            <property name="maxlines">0K</property> <!-- \d+[KMG]? Suffixes are in terms of thousands -->
            <property name="daily">true</property> <!-- Automatically rotates when a log message is written after midnight -->
            <property name="maxbackup">10</property> <!-- Max backup for logs rotation -->
      </filter>
    </logging>
```

Personally, I preferred zarolog : https://github.com/rs/zerolog

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example which can have two logs:

```
{
  "console": {
    "enable": true,
    "level": "ERROR"
  },
  "files": [{
    "enable": true,
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "filename":"./log/sys.log",
    "category": "syslog",
    "pattern": "[%D %T] [%L] (%S) %M",
    "rotate": true,
    "maxsize": "5M",
    "maxlines": "10K",
    "daily": true
  },
    {
      "enable": true,
      "level": "INFO",
      "filename":"./log/market.log",
      "category": "marketlog",
      "pattern": "[%D %T] [%L] (%S) %M",
      "rotate": false,
      "maxsize": "10M",
      "maxlines": "20K",
      "daily": false
    }
  ]
}
```

usage in code:

```
log4go.LOGGER("syslog").Info("...")
log4go.LOGGER("marketlog").Debug("...")
```

the debug calls on marketlog would not be written in this case because the "INFO" level automatically filters it out.